# is it possible to programmatically check the service provider for a cell number?

Tags: .net, sql, winapi, api

is there a database or API available where i can enter a cell phone number and it will spit out whoever the providor is like tmobile or verizon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this:

http://blog.programmableweb.com/2010/04/20/free-phone-number-lookup-service-gets-you-location-and-carrier/

I'd say the answer is yes.  The availability of an API to do so, however is questionable.

Edit:

Link to API is in the page.

http://help.cloudvox.com/faqs/digits/digits-phone-number-location-lookup-api

Comment: actually i would like to tell you that there is an exception to this. if perhaps you signed up with verizon and transferred to tmobile, you are still registered with verizon and therefor cloudvox will return verizon

Comment: I see.  I never actually used it, just found it when you asked.  I assume that doesn't meet your needs?  Have you found anything that does?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, such services do exist. I don't know of any free ones (because of the nature of the problem, I don't think free ones *can* exist). For example, [mBlox](http://www.mblox.com/products/operator-id/) has a service you can hook into.

**Edit** wow, there *are* free ones, thanks to Chapso :)

Comment: No problem.  My Google-fu is strong today.

Comment: Googled "api get service provider from phone number"

Comment: @Chapso: I was actually just answering from experience: we've used mblox in the past (though not for this specifically) and they're really good... should've googled first perhaps :)